# My dropdown only shows first words of my selected element (occurred with IE only)

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown on my view:

[image]

I noticed (when page is loaded) the element in my dropdown is not showed completely. If the element is composed of 4 words, only the first 3 are showed.

If I click on it, I can see the element completely.

[image]

If have the same behaviour on all my dropdowns **only with Internet Explorer**.

Any idea?

How to avoid this?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

Here is the CSS:

[image]

I noticed that if I unclick the checkbox of blue line on the above screenshot I don't have this problem. This is the jQuery theme CSS. How is this possible? Why is this dropdown not clever enough (at least at page loaded) to adjust?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest checking the CSS or style for the select. What is the CSS for selects or options?

Comment: I updated my question to show CSS. The version of IE is 9. Thank you guys.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced with the code posted. Please provide a minimal document that exhibits the problem.

Comment: If I include jquery.ui.all.css then the problem occurred. I don't have defined any other CSS.

Comment: I have a live demo of the problem here: http://screencast.com/t/kVRvfYDy9vp